# The "Anatomy of a Topic" image in Kafka docs confuses me. Does each "0" refer to the same data?

Tags: apache-kafka

Check out this picture:

[image]

Do the three "0"s refer to three different pieces of data, or are all three exactly the same data being stored?

Comment: Data replicates across brokers, not partitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zeros refer to the respective partitions' offsets. From the documentation (just below the diagram you pasted):

> Each partition is an ordered, immutable sequence of records that is
>   continually appended to—a structured commit log. The records in the
>   partitions are each assigned a sequential id number called the offset
>   that uniquely identifies each record within the partition.

In Kafka each message has an offset in the partition it's in that indicates its position. All partitions start from offset 0 and the offset is incremented for every new message. That guarantees the message order within the partition.

In your example, at offset 0 each partition will have whatever you sent first to the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Think these partition as 3 different containers which contains the data of the same topic. Actually what happens when we send some data to a kafka producer, it has various logic to put that data into certain kafka topic.

We send ProfucerRecord to a kafka producer.

The ProducerRecord has structure like this. 
New ProducerRecord(topic, partition, key1, value1) , callback);

Say we have topic Test which has 3 partition 
0, 1, 2

1. When we define the the partition:
   If we have defined the partition in the ProducerRecord it will go into that partition

If we send these 3 records to the topic Test.

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test, 0, 1, “A”))
The offset of the partition 0 will be 0

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test, 1, 2, “B”))
The offset of the partition 1 will be 0

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test, 2, 3, “C”))
The offset of the partition 2 will be 0

2. When we don’t define partition or partition = null

Then it send data into partition in round robin fashion.

3. On the basis of the key in ProducerRecord.

In this case to choose partition, producer generates the hash code and the partitioning logic is.

```
hashCode % number of partition
```

Assume (hashCode for key 1) % 3 (number of partition) gives 0
For  (hasCode of 2 ) % 3 gives 1
And for  (hashCode of 3) %3 gives 2

Which insure the data will always go into the same partition of the key is same.

If we send these 6 message to topic Test.

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test, 1, “A”))
The offset of the partition 0 will be 0

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test,  1, “B”))
The offset of the partition 0 will be 1

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test,  1, “C”))
The offset of the partition 0 will be 2

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test, 1, “D”))
The offset of the partition 0 will be 3

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test, 2, “E”))
The offset of the partition 1 will be 0

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test, 2, “F”))
The offset of the partition 1 will be 1

producer.send( New ProducerRecord(Test,  3, “G”))
The offset of the partition 2 will be 0